# parsing data from parent to child component in angular 4 using only html

Tags: angular

I have written a component in angular 4 that has only an html player, and the idea was, for each component where the video is needed, to parse the src from the parent using only HTML, so to look something like this:

PARENT COMPONENT

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-my-video src="./path/myvideo"></app-my-video>
</div>
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source "put the src from the parent here" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Hope makes sense. If such approach is not possible, could you suggest an alternative? 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Input()` directive, [read more](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding).

```
class MyVideoComponent {
  @Input() src: string;
}


<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source [src]="src">
</video>
```